# Is a std::unique_ptr cleaned up automatically after scope when given as reference?

Tags: c++, reference, smart-pointers

It is possible to return with a pointer for a function, and this is useful for lots of reasons, but is it suggested to take reference from that return value?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

unique_ptr<int> give_a_number(){
    return std::make_unique<int>(6);
}

int main(){
   int& ret = *give_a_number();
   return ret;
}
```

According to the sanitizer, no leaks occur :

```
user@comp: Scrapbook$ g++ main.cpp -fsanitize=address -g
user@comp: Scrapbook$
```

So the reference is cleaned up somehow, but I fail to understand why.
How does the clean-up happen, and even how the unque_ptr is able to keep track of the data. 
Should this be consdered as safe behavior?
Is this an accepted usage in the community?

Comment: Doesn't `*give_a_number()` give just an `int` value? Why should it leak?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no leak here. In general an object owned by a `std::unique_ptr` is *never* leaked, as long as `.release()` is not called on the owning `std::unique_ptr`.

Your program does however have undefined behavior because the lifetimes are not correct. If you store a reference or pointer to the owned object you take over some responsibility to assure correct object lifetimes.

`give_a_number()` returns, by-value, a `std::unique_ptr` owning the `int` object. This `std::unique_ptr` is therefore materialized as a temporary object in the statement

```
int& ret = *give_a_number();
```

You don't move this temporary into any persistent `std::unique_ptr` instance. So when the temporary object is destroyed at the end of the statement, the `int` it owns is destroyed as well. Now your reference is dangling.

You then use the dangling reference in `return ret;`, causing undefined behavior.

You can store a reference to the owned object, but if you do so, you must assure that the `std::unique_ptr` instance owning the reference out-lives the `int` reference to avoid lifetime issues. E.g. the following are fine:

```
int main(){
   return *give_a_number(); // `std::unique_ptr` temporary outlives return value initialization
}
```

```
int main(){
   auto ptr = give_a_number(); // `ptr` lives until `main` returns
   int& ret = *ptr;
   return ret;
}
```

Usually it is safer to just store the smart pointer in an automatic variable  as above and obtain the object by dereferencing with `*ptr`, where needed. The `std::unique_ptr` and the object it owns then live until the end of the block, if it is not moved from.

But it is perfectly correct to e.g. pass `*ptr` to a function by-reference. Since `ptr` outlives such a function call, there will not be any problem.

This also works if you pass `*give_a_number()` directly as argument to a function, because the `std::unique_ptr` temporary will outlive such a call as well. But in that case the `std::unique_ptr` and the object it owns will live only until the end of the statement (full-expression), not the end of the block.

Answer (score 3):

unique_ptr lives only in an expression with *give_a_number*. Pointer to int is destroyed before *return* statement.

One may see how it behaves by using non-POD A with logging destructor and constructor calls.

```
struct A
{
  A() { std::cout << "A created\n"; }
  ~A() { std::cout << "A destroyed\n"; }
};

unique_ptr<A> give_a_number(){
  return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A());
}

int main(){
  std::cout << "start\n";
  A& ret = *give_a_number();
  std::cout << "reference to removed object here\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
start
A created
A destroyed
reference to removed object here
```

I don't know why sanitizer does not print alert in your case because mine does when called on your code. I use g++ 5.3.1

```
==21820==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60200000eff0 at pc 0x000000400bd5 bp 0x7ffee5f3cac0 sp 0x7ffee5f3cab8
READ of size 4 at 0x60200000eff0 thread T0
```

Comment: hmm-- maybe because the compiler optimizes the statements somehow? Anyhow, thank you for your answer!